# Reading data from BLE device with web bluetooth?

Tags: javascript, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt

I'm new to javascript so i might have some unconventional way of programming. 
That said, I'm working on a project where I need to read and write data to a custom BLE device.
I'm using the gatt server protocol for the connection.
I'm able to make a connection with the device but now i'm trying to read data from the registers.

I looked trough the web samples from google as well as the web bluetooth github but I cant make any sense of it. The code below is my current attempt to break this. earlier tries had me get stuck on the fact that the value that I got was an object or a promise object.

```
function readFromPcb() {
    let p2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (device.connected === false) {
            reject('network Error');
        }
    })
        .then(characteristic => {
            readValue = characteristic.readValue();
            console.log('data is: ' + readValue);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('error: ' + error + DOMException.name);
        });
}
```

Comment: This question looks very similar to the one you posted earlier: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57968195/web-bluetooth-with-promises Are you sure that these are 2 different questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work! I needed to access web bluetooth's characteristic level. After that I could use the promise of my connect function to chain the .then to my read function.

thanks for the help.

```
function readFromPcb() {
    prom.then(_ => {
        console.log('getting data...');
        gattChar.readValue();
    })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('error: ' + error + ' ' + DOMException.name);
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Web Bluetooth, but I notice your top promise never resolves. It either rejects if the device is not connected, or else... does nothing. If you want the `then` callbacks to run, you need to call `resolve()` at some point in your main promise. That said, since you explicitly constructed this promise, the value it resolves with will just be whatever argument you pass into `resolve()` yourself; that doesn't sound like what you want. What function is supposed to give you the "characteristic"? That's the one that probably returns a promise and you don't need to construct one yourself, you can just chain the other `then` callbacks onto the promise it returns for you.

Comment: I get my "characteristic" from my connect function, the one that makes the initial connection. Could you maybe explain how i can use that promise as a call back for this function? I don't have a full understanding of promises so I try my best.

Comment: A quick skim of the MDN docs says that a GATT server's `connect` function returns a promise. So you should just be chaining your `.then` callbacks onto the end of the connect function, not making your own Promise.